# Upgrading WSO2 Iot Server 3.1.0 to 3.3.0

Tags: mysql, wso2, upgrade, ibm-api-management, wso2-iot

I have worked on WSO2 IOT server version 3.1.0 with MySQL database on Windows Machine for quit some time now. WSO2 has recently released Server version 3.3.0. So now I want to upgrade my server. I tried running the WSO2 IoT server 3.3.0 by pointing the database to mysql in the datasources xml file. The problem I am facing when I run the server is, some of the APIs fail to get published with the following exception and APIs stay in CREATED state and I am not able to use those APIs.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-10-04 14:03:07,845] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl} -  Error while adding new API : admin-Android Device Management-0.9.0 - Scope 'perm:android:enroll' is already used by another API. {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Scope 'perm:android:enroll' is already used by another API.
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.addScopes(ApiMgtDAO.java:7171)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.addAPI(ApiMgtDAO.java:4876)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.addAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:654)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.addAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:59)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl.apisPost(ApisApiServiceImpl.java:281)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.ApisApi.apisPost(ApisApi.java:574)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor273.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:192)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:191)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.authenticator.framework.WebappAuthenticationValve.invoke(WebappAuthenticationValve.java:46)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
TID: [-1] [] [2018-10-04 14:03:07,898] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherStartupHandler} -  failed to publish api. {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherStartupHandler}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.exception.APIManagerPublisherException: feign.FeignException: status 500 reading APIIndividualApi#apisPost(API,String,String); content:
{"code":500,"message":"Internal server error","description":"Error while adding new API : admin-Android Device Management-0.9.0 - Scope 'perm:android:enroll' is already used by another API.","moreInfo":"","error":[]}
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherServiceImpl.publishAPI(APIPublisherServiceImpl.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherStartupHandler.publishAPIs(APIPublisherStartupHandler.java:97)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherStartupHandler.access$500(APIPublisherStartupHandler.java:30)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherStartupHandler$1.run(APIPublisherStartupHandler.java:69)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: feign.FeignException: status 500 reading APIIndividualApi#apisPost(API,String,String); content:
{"code":500,"message":"Internal server error","description":"Error while adding new API : admin-Android Device Management-0.9.0 - Scope 'perm:android:enroll' is already used by another API.","moreInfo":"","error":[]}
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:62)
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:91)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.apisPost(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherServiceImpl.publishAPI(APIPublisherServiceImpl.java:56)
    ... 4 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-10-04 14:03:08,953] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl} -  Error while adding new API : admin-Android Configuration Management-0.9.0 - Scope 'perm:android:enroll' is already used by another API. {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Scope 'perm:android:enroll' is already used by another API.
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.addScopes(ApiMgtDAO.java:7171)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.addAPI(ApiMgtDAO.java:4876)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.addAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:654)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.addAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:59)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl.apisPost(ApisApiServiceImpl.java:281)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.ApisApi.apisPost(ApisApi.java:574)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor273.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:192)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:191)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.authenticator.framework.WebappAuthenticationValve.invoke(WebappAuthenticationValve.java:46)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
TID: [-1] [] [2018-10-04 14:03:08,967] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherStartupHandler} -  failed to publish api. {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherStartupHandler}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.exception.APIManagerPublisherException: feign.FeignException: status 500 reading APIIndividualApi#apisPost(API,String,String); content:
{"code":500,"message":"Internal server error","description":"Error while adding new API : admin-Android Configuration Management-0.9.0 - Scope 'perm:android:enroll' is already used by another API.","moreInfo":"","error":[]}
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherServiceImpl.publishAPI(APIPublisherServiceImpl.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherStartupHandler.publishAPIs(APIPublisherStartupHandler.java:97)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherStartupHandler.access$500(APIPublisherStartupHandler.java:30)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherStartupHandler$1.run(APIPublisherStartupHandler.java:69)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: feign.FeignException: status 500 reading APIIndividualApi#apisPost(API,String,String); content:
{"code":500,"message":"Internal server error","description":"Error while adding new API : admin-Android Configuration Management-0.9.0 - Scope 'perm:android:enroll' is already used by another API.","moreInfo":"","error":[]}
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:62)
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:91)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.apisPost(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherServiceImpl.publishAPI(APIPublisherServiceImpl.java:56)
    ... 4 more
```

I tried to publish these APIs in carbon console but it could not be published due to the following error.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-10-04 16:25:58,825] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.custom.lifecycles.checklist.util.InvokeAspectUtil} -  Failed to invoke action Deploy as a Prototype of aspect APILifeCycle on resource /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/admin/Android Device Management/0.9.0/api. An exception occurred while executing handler chain. null {org.wso2.carbon.governance.custom.lifecycles.checklist.util.InvokeAspectUtil}
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: An exception occurred while executing handler chain. null
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.invokeAspect(HandlerManager.java:2816)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.invokeAspect(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:518)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.invokeAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2607)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.invokeAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:510)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.invokeAspect(UserRegistry.java:1952)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.custom.lifecycles.checklist.util.InvokeAspectUtil.invokeAspect(InvokeAspectUtil.java:52)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.custom.lifecycles.checklist.services.LifecyclesAdminService.invokeAspect(LifecyclesAdminService.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:441)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.custom.lifecycles.checklist.stub.CustomLifecyclesChecklistAdminServiceStub.invokeAspect(CustomLifecyclesChecklistAdminServiceStub.java:667)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.custom.lifecycles.checklist.ui.clients.LifecycleServiceClient.invokeAspect(LifecycleServiceClient.java:120)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.custom.lifecycles.checklist.ui.processors.InvokeAspectProcessor.invokeAspect(InvokeAspectProcessor.java:56)
    at org.apache.jsp.lifecycles.invoke_005faspect_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(invoke_005faspect_005fajaxprocessor_jsp.java:88)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.URLBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(URLBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.authenticator.framework.WebappAuthenticationValve.invoke(WebappAuthenticationValve.java:46)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.getAPI(APIUtil.java:668)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.executors.APIExecutor.execute(APIExecutor.java:111)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.runCustomExecutorsCode(DefaultLifeCycle.java:712)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.invoke(DefaultLifeCycle.java:450)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler.invokeAspect(GovernanceEventingHandler.java:344)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.invokeAspect(HandlerManager.java:2792)
    ... 87 more
```

Screenshot of MySQL table for the APIs with created state along with query. Used this query to see of all the APIs have been published.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.reg_path_value,
    p.reg_path_id,
    pr.reg_id,
    pr.reg_name,
    pr.reg_value
FROM wso2carbon_DB.reg_path p
    INNER JOIN wso2carbon_DB.reg_resource r
    ON p.reg_path_id = r.reg_path_id

    INNER JOIN wso2carbon_DB.reg_resource_property rp
    ON rp.reg_version = r.reg_version

    INNER JOIN wso2carbon_DB.reg_property pr
    ON rp.reg_property_id = pr.reg_id
WHERE r.reg_name='api'
AND pr.reg_name='STATUS';
```

[Table.PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXaAV.png)

I ve been struggling with this for the past 2 weeks. Is there a straight forward way I can upgrade the WSO2 IoT server from 3.1.0 to 3.3.0?

Database: Mysql 5.7
OS: Windows/Linux

Any help is deeply appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are facing is due to a missing argument in the server startup script. Please open up the iot-server.bat file with a text editor and include the following argument in the correct section, located towards the end of the file.

-Denable-api-scopes-sharing="true"

Hope this helps.